# Can this be more optimised : find unique element(element appears only one time among the two lists)

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

example : if a = [1,2] and b =[1] , output is 2 because it is unique among the two lists

Assume there is exactly one such number.

The unique number can be in either of the two lists.

```
def find_me(x, y):
    for element in x:
        if element not in y:
            return element
    for element in y:
        if element not in x:
            return element

first_list = [14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1]
second_list = [2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50]

print find_me(first_list,second_list)

#output : -4
```

I get the expected result with this code.

I want to know whether this can be further optimised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `list.count()` function:

```
first_list = [14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1]
second_list = [2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50]

merged = first_list + second_list
unique_item = [i for i in merged if merged.count(i) == 1]
print(unique_item)    # [-4]
```

---

Or using **set** object:

```
unique_item = set(first_list) ^ set(second_list)
print(unique_item)    # {-4}
```

Comment: @MathewAlex, you did not mention **speed optimisation** in your question. Make some benchmark

Comment: Yeah. But if I wanted to solve the problem faster, is your code the one I'm looking for..?

Comment: @MathewAlex, on such small lists speed would not be an issue. If your lists would contain thousands or millions numbers - then, we can perform some comparison